# jquery append() not working on select tag

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

```
$document.ready(function () {
    $("#policy1").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $("#policyShow").append(new Option("Temporary", ""));
        }
        $("#policy2").change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $("#policyShow").append(new Option("employee", ""));
            }
        });
    });
```

In the jquery code here i wanted to append some text onto the select box when i check a check box. but it does not works.

Comment: $document.ready( looks like this bracket is not closed. Is there any error in console?

Comment: @monu when you edit do not fix the syntax errors...

Comment: Works fine when syntax errors are fixed http://jsfiddle.net/yJeFh/ i dont know if it's intended to delegate policy2 when changing policy1, but i'd suggest you to put it outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
$("#policy1").change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $("#policyShow").append($("<option/>", { html: "Temporary" }));
            }
            $("#policy2").change(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    $("#policyShow").append(($("<option/>", { html: "employee" }));
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

That may not work in IE8. Try this:

```
 var o = new Option("Temporary", "value");
  /// jquerify the DOM object 'o' so we can use the html method
 $(o).html("Temporary");
 $("#policyShow").append(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("#policy1").change(function() {
     if($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $("#policyShow").append( '<option value="">Option Two</option>' );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("#policyShow").append($("<option>Temporary</option>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

only your syntax are wrong try this:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#policy1").change(function() {
         if(this.checked) {
             $("#policyShow").append(new Option("Temporary", "t"));
          }
     });
    $("#policy2").change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            $("#policyShow").append(new Option("employee", "e"));
        }
     });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="policyShow"></select>
<input type="checkbox" value="yes" id="policy1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="yes" id="policy2" />
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)**